# Estimated binomial success probability from repeated experiments (in matlab)

Tags: matlab, data-fitting

Suppose I have a binomial process with success probability p.  I do an experiment with N=4 trials and obtain a number of successes (0-4).  Now, suppose I repeat that experiment 10,000 times (4 trials in every experiment) to obtain a distribution of numbers of successes, which looks something like this:

[image]

Note that, because of the way the experiment is done, I cannot record data for experiments with 0 successes, although this undoubtedly happens at some frequency.  This is why there is no bar for 0 on the graph.

How can I fit these data to estimate the probability p (and, ideally, a confidence interval if I know the number of experiments and not just the proportions)?  My preference is to use MATLAB, but I'm open to using any tool that will do the job.

***UPDATE***

I can fit the data using `mle`, but the fit is not good (see image below).  I think the problem is the missing data (experiments with 0 successes are not observed).  Can I somehow tell `mle` to only fit the data within a certain range and ignore other values?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question, but have you read the documentation: [http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/binopdf.html](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/binopdf.html)?

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation.  It didn't help.  I don't want to calculate a PDF for a binomial distribution given known p and N; I want to take experimental data (where N is known and p is not), and fit a PDF to those data (using least squares or MLE for example) to extract p.  I read about MATLAB's binofit function, but it seems designed to deal with a single experiment with a large number of trials, rather than lots of repeated experiments each with a small number of trials.

Comment: What about [http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitdist.html](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitdist.html)?

Comment: Please see my update that clarifies the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example we have a custom truncated binomial distribution. Matlab has `fitdist` function but only accept predefined distributions and do not accept cumstom distribution .  As you noted that you are open to use any tool, I show estimation of the p parameter with `R` ,however in Matlab with the maximum likelihood method the parameter can be estimated.
if we calculate values of density function of binomial distribution with `p = 0.3` for `4 expriments`  we have:

```
>> den = dbinom(x=0:4, size=4, prob=0.3)
>> print(den)
 0.2401, 0.4116, 0.2646, 0.0756, 0.0081
```

that sum of them = 1
since 0 values are missing from the data 
we have :

```
 0.4116, 0.2646, 0.0756, 0.0081
```

sum of them is less than 1 .for it we divide each with `(1-den[1])`

```
>> print(den[-1] / (1-den[1]))
0.54165022 0.34820371 0.09948677 0.01065930
```

now sum of them is 1. This way we can make a custon distribution.

`fitdistr` from `MASS` package can fit a user provided density to data so the solution in R is:

```
library(MASS) # required for fitdistr

#generate 10000 samples from binomial distribution
smpl <- rbinom(n=10000,size=4,prob=.3)

#exclude zeros
smpl <- smpl[-which(smpl==0)]

# custom truncated density
truncated_dbinom <- function(x, prob){
    dbinom(x, 4, prob)/(1-dbinom(0, 4, prob));
}

#fit distribution to data
out <- fitdistr(smpl, truncated_dbinom,list(prob=.5),method = "Brent",lower=0,upper=1)

#estimate of p
print(out$estimate)

#standard deviation
print(out$sd)
```

result:

```
[1] 0.3092295
[1] 0.01070016
```

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful reply.  I also found this page useful: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/fitting-custom-univariate-distributions.html.  

In MATLAB, I ended up using the command

`custpdf = @(x,p) binopdf(x,4,p)./(1-binocdf(0,4,p));`

to generate the custom truncated binomial distribution, and 

`[phat,pci] = mle(data,'pdf',custpdf,'start',0.7);`

to fit the data.